# How Can I Create a Custom Unordered Map Comparor That Ignores Certain Keys When Checking Equality?

Tags: c++, lambda, unordered-map

I'd like to create a custom comparison function to send to `find_if` or another comparison function that, for the purpose of equality comparison, requires me to ignore certain keys.

I have a set that contains an unordered map. Let's call this vecMap. vecMaplooks like `std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>>`.

In my scenario, I want two `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>` to be equal if and only if the keys whose second value is not `true` are equal. For instance,

For instance,

*MapOne Content:*

```
Keys | Values
{1, false} | 10
{2, true}  | 15
```

*MapTwo Content:*

```
Keys | Values
{1, false} | 10
```

These two maps are considered are equal, since we only care about the equality of keys whose key.second is false.

Another example,

*MapOne Content:*

```
Keys | Values
{1, false} | 200
{2, true}  | 15
```

*MapTwo Content:*

```
Keys | Values
{1, false} | 10
```

These two maps are considered **not** equal, since the quantity for the only key that is equal is different.

How can I create a lambda expression that implements this type of equality?

My end goal is to have a `std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>>` which contains unordered maps that have keys that are true and find the corresponding map which is equal to another map which will never have a key that is true.

For example,

```
using mapVec = std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>>;

mapVec s{};

// Fill s with unordered maps
// g = std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>
// customEquality = [](){}; (some lambda)?

mapVec::iterator it = s.find(g, customEquality);
```

I want a find_if algorithm that takes both my `std::unorderd_map<std::pair<int, bool>, int>` and my custom lambda comparor. If there's an even simpler way, I'm all ears.

Comment: You mention "equal", however `std::set` uses `operator <` or strict-weak-order to order the elements, not equality / inequality.

Comment: I just want a container to hold these in, it can be a vector as well. I will edit my question. EDIT: Changed.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, why is the **bool** part of the key?

The other point is that if your unordered map is quite large (say many thousand items) or the item are much more complex that the sample code above, your search might be very inefficient.

So in that case, it would make much more sense to use a 
`std::vector<std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>>` instead.

Given that a map is used, it is relatively easy to compare two maps by using `std::lexicographical_compare` and an appropriate comparison function as map content is  sorted .

And that comparison function would only compare the first item of each pair (true count).

If a `key` exists in one map nut not in the other and the *true* count is not 0, then it is a mismatch.

Map 1 content would then be:

```
1, 0, 10
2, 15, 0
```

- First number is equivalent to your key.first
- Second number is the *true* count (your value when your key.second is true)
- Third number is the *true* count (your value when your key.second is false)

---

There are many other alternatives but one need to know how the data is used to know what could be appropriate. Here are some ideas:

- Would it be more appropriate to put *true* and *false* data in separate containers?

  - For each item in the vectors?
  - Or using distinct vectors?
- Does the data is used mainly only for matching purpose?

  - If so, using a `set` of `tuple` might make some algorithm easier to write.
  - Also, it might be possible to invert the order of the `bool` and `int` in the key so that the search could be applied to a subrange (the *true* part) which could easily be found by searching `lower_bound` of `{true, INT_MIN }`.